# R.Id. cannot be resolved or is not a field - Can't find the mistake

Tags: java, android, eclipse

From looking online, I know there is some problem with my XML file but not sure what it is. I've tried remaking the entire button from scratch but the error persists. The following is the code in the activity.

```
package com.example.linked1n;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import com.example.linked1n.R;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

Button login;
int counter;
EditText username, password;
String success;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    counter = 3;
    username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.getEmail);
    password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.getPassword);   

    login = (Button)findViewbyId(R.Id.login);
    login.setOnClickListener(this);  

}

private void loginClick() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ScreenAftLog.class );
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void onClick (View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.Id.login:
            loginClick();
            break;
    }
}
```

This is the XML code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.linked1n.MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:onClick="loginClick"
    android:text="@string/yayaya" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/getEmail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textWebEmailAddress" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/getPassword"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/getEmail"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help will be appreciated!
Edit: adding  doesn't fix it

Comment: Your relativeLayout is not closed.

Comment: Closed the relativeLayout and switched requestFocus out of Edittext. still nothing :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not `R.Id.login`, it should be `R.id.login`

Comment: I tried that before but a combination of everyone's edits made it work! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote ID in caps in your switch statement. `id` is a reserved word and needs to be in small letter, change the R.Id.login to `R.id.login`, then run  :)

Answer (score 0):

End tag is missing for the parent layout ...

Add `</RelativeLayout>` tag at the end. If the problem still persists, let us know.

Remove the last line - `</EditText>`

Below is your XML file which i build successfully. Try this.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.linked1n.MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:onClick="loginClick"
    android:text="Sample" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/getEmail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textWebEmailAddress" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/getPassword"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/getEmail"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <requestFocus />
</RelativeLayout>
```

java file

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

Button login;
int counter;
EditText username, password;
String success;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    counter = 3;
    username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.getEmail);
    password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.getPassword);   

    login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
    login.setOnClickListener(this);  

}

private void loginClick() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ScreenAftLog.class );
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void onClick (View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.login:
            loginClick();
            break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Problem still persists

Comment: @PranavAnand, check your XML file name. It should not contain Capital letters.

Comment: It doesn't. actvitiy_main.xml

Comment: @PranavAnand, Hope it should work now. Mark it as answer if it works. Or please let me know if you still face the issue

Comment: Error remains with your XML file as well unfortunately